# Pointwise limit of $\sum{\frac{1}{n} \left(\frac{2z-i}{2+iz}\right)^n}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

I am trying to find the set $\Omega$ where the series
$$ \sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{1}{n} \left(\frac{2z-i}{2+iz}\right)^n $$ exhibits pointwise convergence.

I have thought of several approaches:

- Turning (somehow) the series into some power series and then computing the convergence radius using the tools I've been given.
- Seeing where $\frac{|2z-i|}{|2 + iz|} < 1$
  but I haven't managed to have success through the computations.

Any idea of how I should tackle this problem?

Comment: @hardmath fixed. Thanks for the tip

Comment: In the complex plane the open unit disk $|u|\lt 1$ is bounded by a circle.  It is worth knowing that a linear fractional transformation ([Moebius map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation)) sends circles & lines to circles & lines, so the preimage of the unit disk under that map will not be very complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Let us see where $\left\|\frac{2z-i}{2+iz}\right\|<1$ holds. Assuming $z=s+it$ with $s,t\in\mathbb{R}$, the previous constraint is equivalent to:

$$\|2z-i\|^2 = (2s)^2+(2t-1)^2 < (2-t)^2+s^2 = \|2+iz\|^2 $$
or to:
$$  s^2+t^2 < 1 $$
i.e. the series is uniformly convergent over any compact subset of the open disk $\|z\|<1$ and not convergent outside that disk. Now you just have to study what happens on the boundary of such disk. It is useful to recall that for any $z$ such that $\|z\|<1$ the identity:
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{z^n}{n} = -\log(1-z)$$
holds, and:
$$\frac{2e^{i\theta}-i}{2+ie^{i\theta}}=e^{-i\theta}\frac{2e^{i\theta}-i}{2e^{-i\theta}+i}=e^{-i\theta}\frac{w}{\bar{w}}=e^{i\varphi}. $$